# Copy files until they exceed a specified size

Tags: powershell, filesize, get-childitem

I need to copy files to a folder until they exceed a specified size. I've written the following script but it fails with the following error:

> Cannot compare "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" because it is not IComparable.
>   At C:\33.ps1:8 char:1
>   + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1024MB)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\source -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }

foreach($file in $files) {
    do {

        Copy-Item $file -Recurse D:\target
        $colItems = (Get-ChildItem d:\target -recurse | `
                         Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1024MB)
    }
    while ($colItems -le 10)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while condition will be verified **after** the first do loop. Since you already enumerate through the files, your script will copy **all** files.

You can omit the do-while loop and break the foreach if the limit is reached:

```powershell
$files=Get-ChildItem C:\source -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
$sum = 0
$sizeLimitInGB = 10

foreach($file in $files) 
{
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem d:\target -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

    if (($colItems.sum / 1GB) -gt $sizeLimitInGB)
    {
        break; # Limit reached.
    }

    Copy-Item $file -Recurse D:\target
}
```